# What is the benefit of decomposition and what indicates a class should be decomposed?

Tags: c#

I have heard a lot of rules of thumb about when a class should be decomposed (e.g. your class is getting unmanageably large), but I don't know of a concrete answer to this question.

I am not looking for a "best practice" or "code smells."  For example, if I see duplicated code, I know there is one specific solution: Eliminate the duplicate code by creating a base class or other creating a single method that both can use. This is a example of concrete, specific answer that I am looking for.

But it is not so clear to me when a class should be decomposed into two or more classes.  I can tell you my rule of thumb is that when I see more than one broad responsibility, then I refactor out one of the responsibilities.  But this is more of a "best practice" and I would like to nail this down more exactly.

The closest I have found is the Single Responsibility Principle.  "The single responsibility principle states that every object should have a single responsibility."  But what is a responsibility? How do define that exactly?

Bob Martin says it's a "reason to change." To take a concrete example, lets say you have an app which takes an input, processes it and creates an output.  That would make three areas of change - Input  (It could be from a string, or XML).  The Processor could change in it's rules.  And the output could change: It could be string or XML or database. So it would give you three classes at the top level.

Again, not looking for debate or best practice, but if there is a solid principle of decomposition.  Or perhaps, a solid principle of composition would be a better way of stating it.

The motivation for me behind decomposition is composition -- I have found highly composed apps are much more flexible and easy to work with.

Another reason for decomposition is so that I, as a developer, by just looking at the classes, can better understand the whole application.  To have a clear understanding of a class I suppose would require the class has a single clear cut purpose. While this has to do with class naming, I think that if a class has such a purpose, it would be the most understandable and thus be a good basis for decomposition.

To apply this to the example above, it would be obvious where to look if I needed to do maintenance on the Input, Processing, or Output, I start at the obvious class as each has an obvious purpose. (But I am just thinking out loud here to try to clarify it for myself.)

So the question is: What is the benefit of decomposition and what indicates a class should be decomposed?

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. You've answered your own question quite well.

Comment: OK, well maybe I just had to think it through. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but in C#, there's nothing stopping you of creating partial class to seperate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to single responsibility, a good example is the data layer of an application. In most of my small apps I have one repository that handles all the reading/writing of data from a single database. In most cases it's responsible for dealing with one object type, but in some I have queries that return complex objects, or simple strings.

Some overzealous developers would go so far as to say that I should not have methods that deal with my domain objects as well as ones that return simple data like strings and ints. In situations like this you have to use your best judgement in determining when your class is unfocused or bloated, and refactor accordingly.